# Heroku deploy backend Nestjs + React js as frontend build not succeeding

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, nestjs

After hours of reading this tricky build for Heroku using nestjs as backend and reactjs as frontend separately with MySQL still react app does not succeed building into heroku, failing "react-scripts: not found" which I have copy from the devdependencies to dependencies.
I would like some suggestions/guidance on the clear steps from the react part setup to make the build successful with nestjs (separately).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I finally realized that I didn't made the 'git init' command that successful create the build after that. Thanks for your reply.